# Вывести отдельную корзину в мобильной версии [Opencart 2]

Tags: javascript, ajax, opencart

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно вывести в common/header.tpl два раза: `<?php echo $cart; ?>`? Сейчас все отображается корректно, но есть проблема с добавлением товаров. Когда в мобильной версии добавляю товар, корзина не обновляется, не работает AJAX, добавленные товары показывает только после полной перезагрузки страницы.

OC: Opencart 2.3.0.2
Тема: Default

```html
<body class="<?php echo $class; ?>">
  <!-- Start PC -->
  <nav id="top" class="hidden-xs">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-2">
       <div class="city hidden-xs">
        <!-- <?php echo $currency; ?> -->
        Город: <span>Санкт-Петербург</span>
        <!-- <?php echo $language; ?> -->
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-7 hidden-sm">
      <div class="link hidden-xs">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/index.php?route=information/information&information_id=7">Доставка и оплата</a></li>
          <!-- <li><a href="#">Гарантия и возрат</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li> -->
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-3">
        <div id="top-links" class="nav pull-right">
          <ul class="list-inline">
            <li class="hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-lg"><a href="<?php echo $contact; ?>"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></a> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md"><?php echo $telephone; ?></span></li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="<?php echo $account; ?>" title="<?php echo $text_account; ?>" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md"><?php echo $text_account; ?></span> <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                <?php if ($logged) { ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $account; ?>"><?php echo $text_account; ?></a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $order; ?>"><?php echo $text_order; ?></a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $transaction; ?>"><?php echo $text_transaction; ?></a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $download; ?>"><?php echo $text_download; ?></a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $logout; ?>"><?php echo $text_logout; ?></a></li>
                <?php } else { ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $register; ?>"><?php echo $text_register; ?></a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $login; ?>"><?php echo $text_login; ?></a></li>
                <?php } ?>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </nav>
  <header class="hidden-xs">
    <div class="sticky">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
            <div id="logo">
             <!--  <?php if ($logo) { ?> -->
             <!-- <img src="<?php echo $logo; ?>" title="<?php echo $name; ?>" alt="<?php echo $name; ?>" class="img-responsive" /> -->
             <a href="<?php echo $home; ?>" class="logo">
              <span>М</span>АГАЗИН <img src="/image/logo-shop.png" alt="" style="margin-top:-10px;">
              <p><span>Д</span>оставка еды в СПБ</p>
            </a>
            <?php } else { ?>
            <h3><a href="<?php echo $home; ?>"><?php echo $name; ?></a></h3>
            <?php } ?>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-5 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
          <?php echo $search; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-2 hidden-xs">
          <ul class="list-phone">
            <li><a href="mailto:info@shop.net>"></a> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md">info@shop.net</span></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-2 hidden-xs">
          <?php echo $cart; ?>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<!-- End PC -->
<!-- Start Mobile -->
<nav id="top" class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <!-- Start Mobile Logotype -->
      <div class="col-xs-6 hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
        <div id="logo">
          <!--  <?php if ($logo) { ?> -->
          <!-- <img src="<?php echo $logo; ?>" title="<?php echo $name; ?>" alt="<?php echo $name; ?>" class="img-responsive" /> -->
          <a href="<?php echo $home; ?>" class="logo">
            <span>М</span>АГАЗИН <img src="/image/logo-shop.png" alt="" style="margin-top:-10px;">
            <p><span>Д</span>оставка еды в СПБ</p>
          </a>
          <?php } else { ?>
          <h3><a href="<?php echo $home; ?>"><?php echo $name; ?></a></h3>
          <?php } ?>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- End Mobile Logotype -->

      <!-- Start Mobile Account -->
      <div class="col-xs-6 hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
        <div id="top-links" class="nav pull-right">
          <ul class="list-inline">
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="<?php echo $account; ?>" title="<?php echo $text_account; ?>" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md"><?php echo $text_account; ?></span> <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                <?php if ($logged) { ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $account; ?>"><?php echo $text_account; ?></a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $order; ?>"><?php echo $text_order; ?></a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $transaction; ?>"><?php echo $text_transaction; ?></a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $download; ?>"><?php echo $text_download; ?></a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $logout; ?>"><?php echo $text_logout; ?></a></li>
                <?php } else { ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $register; ?>"><?php echo $text_register; ?></a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $login; ?>"><?php echo $text_login; ?></a></li>
                <?php } ?>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- End Mobile Account -->
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="sticky-mobile">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="sticky hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <?php echo $cart; ?>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <?php if ($categories) { ?>
          <nav id="menu" class="navbar hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-lg">
            <div class="navbar-header"><span id="category" class="visible-xs"><?php echo $text_category; ?></span>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
                <?php if ($category['children']) { ?>
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <div class="dropdown-inner">
                      <?php foreach (array_chunk($category['children'], ceil(count($category['children']) / $category['column'])) as $children) { ?>
                      <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        <?php foreach ($children as $child) { ?>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>"><?php echo $child['name']; ?></a></li>
                        <?php } ?>
                      </ul>
                      <?php } ?>
                    </div>
                    <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>" class="see-all"><?php echo $text_all; ?> <?php echo $category['name']; ?></a> </div>
                  </li>
                  <?php } else { ?>
                  <li><a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a></li>
                  <?php } ?>
                  <?php } ?>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </nav>
            <?php } ?>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End Mobile -->
```

Comment: Код где? Или мы должны новую корзину за вас писать?

Comment: @And Прошу прощения, добавил в первом сообщении код header.tpl

Comment: Советую почитать про `@media` запросы.

Comment: @And с удовольствием прочту, если направите меня в правильном направлении, куда мне двигаться. Просто header сайта очень сильно различается от Desktop версии, поэтому попробовал сделать так. Знаю, ужасное решение, но пока не понял, как можно реализовать по другому.

Answer (score 0):

При обновлении информации о товарах в корзине `js` функция обращается к `id="cart"` (такой айди у блока корзины). Это уникальный идентификатор, но сейчас у вас их два на странице. Либо меняйте `id` на `class` с заменой так же в `common.js` в части функции `cart.add` (примерно тут `$('#cart > button').html('...`) или добавляйте в контроллер хедера некую переменную, идентифицирующую браузер (мобильный/десктоптый) и выводите корзины `header.tpl` через условие проверки этой переменной.

Comment: Спасибо, учту. Оказалось, что проблема еще была и в дополнительном модуле на opencart (flycart). Отключил модуль - все заработало.